How do you lock certain cells and hide the formula without protecting the whole worksheet?
I am working in excel, trying to lock my cells and hide the formulas so that they can't be changed without protecting the whole sheet.  I've done the format cells and locked and hid formulas.  It says that after that you have to use the protect sheet option.  When I use the protection option, it locks my whole worksheet and you can't enter data into the cells that they need to, when I only need 3 columns protected as they have my formulas in them.

Before locking the sheet, highlight the cells you want unprotected, go to Format Cells (Command - 1) then in the "protection" tab, uncheck "Locked"
These cells will now remain unlocked when locking the sheet
